# Cannot get full thumbnail size using the_post_thumbnail

Tags: theme-development, themes, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

I cannot get the **full (unmodified)** image size using

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

I have also tried:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

It still returns the cropped image. I can see that the unmodified size is uploaded on the server and there is no problem with that.
I checked using

`print_r(get_intermediate_image_sizes());`

And it returns following sizes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
    [4] => custom_size1
)
```

Why there is no full size? Has something changed in the WordPress recent versions or is it something else? Thanks.

**Edit:** I have figured out that it is the WordPress **srcset** which is adding multiple image sizes in the URL and it uses the smaller image.

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you declared the post thumbnail support? Have you tried calling other image sizes?

Comment: @Abhik I can get all other sizes correctly, so I guess thre is thumbnail support? Only I cannot get the full image size, instead i get the cropped size.

Comment: Can you post the context where you are using `the_post_thumbnail()`? It must be inside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: @cybmeta it's on the single post, within the loop. As I wrote in my question, I can see all other sizes only the **full** size is not among them.

Comment: It's your own theme? Check if the theme doesn't remove the full size.

Comment: You should post an answer explaining what you have found to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add custom thumbnail size with unlimited(very big) hegiht and width in functions.php with following code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'custom', 9999, 9999 );
```

It will not crop any images. So you can use it as `the_post_thumbnail( 'custom' );`

This method looks rough but you can use if other ways don't work. And if you already have images, you can use regenerate thumbnails plugin.